# BI custom visualization

Tags: business-intelligence

I am looking for any Business Intelligence tool with which a custom visualization could be developed.. I should be able to get all report's metadata- all tables, their coordinates, their columns, columns' datatypes and etc. Also I need to be able to export the required report's data preferably in xml, csv or json. In brief- any kind of BI tool with API is needed.

Comment: Power Bi allows you to develop custom visualisations.

Comment: Is it possible to create own visual components using Power BI?

Comment: Yes. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools/